# Trying to enforce http://www in url on a Cake PHP site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My current `.htaccess` file looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

How can I add `http://www.` in all cases?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is independent of the PHP framework as it's best resolved in the Apache configuration (.htaccess):

At the top of your .htaccess file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive, include the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Explanation: If the site is accessed by the bare domain (`example.com`) then redirect to the `www` subdomain.

If you are not using any other subdomains (ie. only `www`) then you could make this completely generic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Explanation: If the *host* does not start with `www.` then redirect to the `www` subdomain.

Comment: That's not working for some reason, any other ideas?

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M
php_value post_max_size 10000M
</IfModule>

Comment: Where are you placing these directives? That can't be your complete .htaccess file; there is no `RewriteEngine` directive? Can you add your entire .htaccess file to your question, the _snippet_ you have posted does not help much. The code I have posted is a standard `www` canonical redirect, so there must be something else (eg. the placement) that is affecting this.

Comment: You were correct, I moved it to the beginning of the file and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful then please up-vote and mark as accepted (if it resolved the problem) by clicking the "tick" on the left hand side. This indicates to others an "accepted solution" exists and removes the question from the "unanswered question" queue. Thanks. :)